# How to use expression.SetFilterDateRange

Tags: excel, vba, office365, pivot-table

I have a simple VBA excel module that activates when I click a text box. (Should)

There is a timeline object `TimelineDTG` with the caption `Date`

Everything up to the last line works, (Sdate and Fdate are based off `TODAY()` both store as `#YYYY-MM-DD#` values in Locals) but
I get a runtime error 5 on the last line (invalid procedure or argument)

```
Sub TimelineStartDayToday()

Dim Sdate As Date
Sdate = Sheets("Settings").Range("V2").Value
Dim Fdate As Date
Fdate = Sheets("Settings").Range("V3").Value

ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("NativeTimeline_Date").TimelineState. _
SetFilterDateRange Sdate, Fdate

End Sub
```

I checked other implementations online and they're exactly the same. There isn't much information from the Microsoft Documentation either.

Comment: What are the values of `Sdate` and `Fdate` when this fails?

Comment: They have dates, for example cell  V3 is based off TODAY() so Locals shows that : Fdate : #2021-09-07# : Date